# Выделить 2 вхождения regex

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть строка :
10.3/3.7/5.3

Как через регулярку выделить только первое и последнее значение,
Только 10.3 и 5.3
Всю голову сломал
Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

использовать надо для удаления этих знаков через preg_replace

Это размеры # д/в/ш, используется это в модуле загрузки товаров на сайт, и там есть вроде можно использовать только preg_replace для какой-то кастомной модификации входящих данных.

Я подумал что если использовать preg_replace (выделить все кроме первого значения) заменить на ""
И останется одно значение которое я смогу грузить на сайт. Далее выделить все кроме второго значения и заменить на "" а оставшиеся значение загрузить на сайт, и после уже выделить все кроме последнего значения заменив на "" а что останется загрузить на сайт.

Comment: Регулярка для любого значения у вас есть?

Comment: В настоящий момент, вопрос не в том, как выделить, а что Вы собираетесь делать с этим выделением.

Comment: 10.3/3.7/5.3 Это размеры, длина/ ширина / высота, через preg_replace я выделенное значение заменяю на пробел, и у меня остаётся только одно значение которое я импортирую на сайт. Использовать там что-то другое нет возможности типа explode.

Comment: @UModeL, в вопросе сказано "удалять".

Comment: Обновил описание проблемы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Регулярное выражение совпадает со всей строкой и выделяет группу между слешами. Замена указывает на группу. После замены в строке остаётся только выделенная группа:

```php
<?php
$pattern = '#.*/(.*)/.*#';
$replacement = '\\1';
$string = '10.3/3.7/5.3';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?>
```

> ```
> $ php replace.php
>
> 3.7
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо большое за помощь.
В результате собрав все мнения с разных источников решил проблему так:
У нас $val = "10.3/3.7/5.3";

```
1) Длина: explode('/', $val)[0] // 10.3
2) Высота: explode('/', $val)[1] // 3.7
3) Ширина: explode('/', $val)[2] // 5.3
```